# Xindy: Encapsulations for Index

Tags: hyperref, indexing, xindy

Well, I struggled to improve my index generated by **Xindy**. I tried to add several entries with bold page numbers by using `\index{...|textbf}` as classified in **latex-loc-fmts.xdy**, without any success.

When running **Xindy** (no matter which way, tex2xindy/texindy/xindy) together with **texindy.xdy**, the following errors are reported (Yes, they are errors because affected entries won't be passed to the generated .ind - IOW not displayed):

```
line X: multiple |'s
...
WARNING: unknown attribute `textbfhyperpage'! (ignored)
```

I've no idea how to handle this behavior and would be pleased, if somebody would share his experiences. BTW: I'm using Xindy-2.4 (TL2012)...

UPDATE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref} % conflict!
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex
\begin{document}
start
Nunc ligula faucibus \index{vel|textbf}. Nullarutrum porttitor...
\index{a}\index{b}\index{ä}\index{z}
end
\printindex
\end{document}
```

...compiled with:

```
latex <file> && xindy -M texindy <file> && latex <file>
```

...results:

It works without `hyperref`, but when it's been crawled it doesn't. Since hyperref is more or less a standard, it's necessary for me to get Xindy working together with hyperref. Any ideas?

Comment: You're probably going to have to post a complete, but minimal, example file for others to test (and hopefully help debug).

Comment: here you are, topic has been updated. it seems hyperref and xindy are in conflict, but I didn't find the trick to get them working together yet...

Comment: I've only found [this two year old discussion](http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/forum.php?thread_name=19370.44958.935362.344482%40puma.r.npc.de&forum_name=xindy-discuss) and no update

Comment: been there, done that... ^^ but i can not believe, in the matter of the ongoing development over the past years, that there's no solution for this (big) issue.

Answer (score 17):

You must use a separate style file for xindy. The following example results in:

[image]

As always I used `imakeidx` to simplify the process. However you have to compile with `shell-escape`.

The trick is to allow `hyperref` to provide a every feature for the index but the writing to the idx-file must be done without any influence by hyperref. This can be achieved by loading `imakeidx` after `hyperref`. The formating rules like `textbf` must be defined in the style file of `xindy`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}


\usepackage[hyperindex=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex[program=texindy,options=-M mystyle.xdy]

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{mystyle.xdy}
;;; xindy style file
(markup-locclass-list :open "\dotfill" :sep "")

(define-attributes (( "textbf" "default" )) )
(markup-locref   :attr  "textbf"     :open "\textbf{\hyperpage{" :close "}}")
(markup-locref   :attr  "textit"     :open "\textit{\hyperpage{" :close "}}")
(markup-locref   :attr  "textttt"     :open "\textttt{\hyperpage{" :close "}}")
(markup-locref   :attr  "texttsc"     :open "\texttsc{\hyperpage{" :close "}}")
(markup-locref   :attr  "default"     :open "\hyperpage{" :close "}")



\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
start
Nunc ligula faucibus \index{vel|textbf}. Nullarutrum porttitor...
\index{a}\index{b}\index{ä}\index{z}
end
\printindex
\end{document}
```

---

Updated version with `see` and `see also` and inside the style file the modul `makeindex` is loaded.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}


\usepackage[hyperindex=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex[program=texindy,options=-M mystyle.xdy]

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{mystyle.xdy}
;;; xindy style file

;;; Load a predefined style:
(require "makeindex.xdy")


(markup-locclass-list :open "\dotfill" :sep "")

(define-attributes (( "textbf" "default" )) )
(markup-locref   :attr  "textbf"     :open "\textbf{\hyperpage{" :close "}}")
(markup-locref   :attr  "textit"     :open "\textit{\hyperpage{" :close "}}")
(markup-locref   :attr  "textttt"     :open "\textttt{\hyperpage{" :close "}}")
(markup-locref   :attr  "texttsc"     :open "\texttsc{\hyperpage{" :close "}}")
(markup-locref   :attr  "default"     :open "\hyperpage{" :close "}")



\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
start
Nunc ligula faucibus \index{vel|textbf}. Nullarutrum porttitor...
\index{a}\index{b}\index{ä}\index{z}
\index{Peter}
\index{Jenny}
\index{Pet|see{Peter}}
\index{Jen|seealso{Jenny}}

end
\printindex
\end{document}
```

Comment: It's a step forward, but it's limited by the fact that you need to define all markup commands in the `.xdy` file. Of course this is way better than nothing!

Comment: Should the `\see` and `\seealso` commands be redefined here as well? They do not seem to be well recognized by xindy.

Comment: @pluton: You can also load modules which support this:  `(require "makeindex.xdy")`

Comment: Thanks but I have not been successful in mimicking the usual makeindex style with xindy.

Comment: The seealso command is ignored and the see command adds the page, while it does not with the original makeindex engine/style.

Comment: @pluton: Please see my update.

Comment: very nice! I tried the xindy makeindex style yesterday but it was giving wrong results. I am not sure why.

Answer (score 7):

If we want sorting in index according to the Swedish sorting rules we usually pass `-C utf8 -L swedish` to `xindy`.

The key problem I found is that we are not able to pass multiple nested parentheses on the input side, the output side, e.g. `markup-locref`, is having no difficulties.

So the mentioned strategy is fine, to turn off generating of the second command, `\hyperpage`, a command used by the [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) package, which is passed to `xindy`, otherwise we would need to handle it anyway by external tools.

Our problem splits into two parts: if we use one single command after the `@` operator (typeset material) or after the `|` operator (index references).

- After the `@` operator I use a new single command where I can use any typeset material, in the following example I pass colors, mathematics, font styles, indentation and other material to the index entry. It is not used for sorting, so `xindy` passes it untouched.
- However, if we use the `|` operator, we don't use backslash in the command and we must notify `xindy` what it is as it is becoming a part of merging, sorting, grouping, tagging etc. We create our own `xdy` file and we use `define-attributes` and `markup-locref` there. Thanks to the `filecontents` package it is easy to have these definitions in the main TeX file.

That solves our two-part problem for most indices. I enclose a simple example and a preview of the first page. I run these three commands to process the example.

> lualatex xindyno1.tex
>   xindy -M texindy -M mal-style -C utf8 -L swedish -o xindyno1.ind xindyno1.idx
>   lualatex xindyno1.tex

```
%! lualatex xindyno1.tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luatextra} % Due to Swedish Ä letter, use inputenc (pdflatex) or fontspec (xelatex) instead.
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[hyperindex=false,colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

\begin{document}
\begin{filecontents*}{mal-style.xdy}
(define-attributes (("texttt" "textsc" "myown")) )
(markup-locref :attr "textbf" :open "\textbf{\hyperpage{" :close "}}")
(markup-locref :attr "textit" :open "\textit{\hyperpage{" :close "}}")
(markup-locref :attr "texttt" :open "\texttt{\hyperpage{" :close "}}")
(markup-locref :attr "textsc" :open "\textsc{\hyperpage{" :close "}}")
(markup-locref :attr "myown" :open "\myown{\hyperpage{" :close "}}")
(markup-locref :attr "hyperpage" :open "\hyperpage{" :close "}")
(markup-locref :attr "default" :open "\hyperpage{" :close "}")
\end{filecontents*}

\def\myshift#1{\makebox[0pt][r]{\texttt{--}}\texttt{#1}}
\def\myown#1{{\Huge#1}}
\def\mycommand#1{{\color{green}#1}}
\def\mydef#1{\texttt{\makebox[0pt][r]{\char"5C}#1}}
\def\mymath#1{{\color{blue}$#1$}}
\def\myfavorite#1{{\color{cyan}\makebox[0pt][r]{I $\heartsuit$\ }{\color{cyan}#1}}}

\begingroup % Print index without page number.
  \def\thispagestyle#1{}
  \pagestyle{empty}
  \printindex
\endgroup

\section{My section}\label{mysection}
I refer to my section~\ref{mysection}.
Start. Nunc ligula faucibus\index{xindy|textbf}. 
\index{vector@Vector}
\index{runme@\mycommand{runme}}
\index{asquared@\mymath{a^2}}
\index{bsquared@\mymath{b^2}}
\index{csquared@\mymath{c^2}}
\index{roof|myown}
\index{mal@\myshift{mal}}
\index{nature@\textbf{Nature}}
\index{home!my own 1}
\index{home!my own 2}
\index{definition@\mydef{definition}}
\index{Velocity}
Nullarutrum porttitor...
\index{alcohol}\index{beauty}\index{älf}\index{zero}
\newpage
\index{vectors@\myfavorite{vectors}}
\index{roof|myown}
\index{roof}
End.
\end{document}
```

[image: Minimum working example]

---

> Next examples of indices

An index is just regular typeset material as any other, usually generated from the `idx` file containing many `\indexentry` commands to the `ind` file, it consists of the `theindex` environment with a bunch of commands, typically with many `\item`, `\indexspace`, `\lettergroup` and `\lettergroupDefault`, which we can redefine, if needed.

I enclose snapshots of my work. The first example contains glyphs of the specific font which we are referring to (picture on left), the second example contains CJKV glyphs, to be more specific, those are kanjis used in Japanese (picture on right).

[image: Two snapshots from my work]